# Loading a heap analyser with LD_PRELOAD, and global scope objects in C++

Tags: c++, linux, global-variables, ld-preload

We have written a heap analyser (for reference known as `lib_debug`) which overrides `free` and `malloc` (and others), primarily to monitor for errors such as memory leaks in our applications, which are deployed on a PPC system running Linux. `lib_debug` is compiled as a shared library, which is loaded with `LD_PRELOAD` as and when needed.

This debugger has worked great up until now; whenever `malloc` is called, a memory monitor singleton is created on the stack, which reports on any un-freed memory when this singleton goes out of scope on exit.

However, one of our applications now allocates a `std::vector` at the global scope. It appears that this global `vector` is being created before our heap analyser is, and most importantly destroyed afterwards. Hence, once in `main` if we insert anything into this `vector`, `lib_debug` thinks we have a memory leak on shutdown.

To illustrate, this is what I believe the sequence of events is:

1. `LD_PRELOAD` loads the symbols from `lib_debug`;
2. `std::vector` is created on stack at global scope;
3. `lib_debug` initialisation occurs - `malloc` has been called somewhere, which causes the actual heap analyser singleton to be created on the stack;
4. Enter `main`;
5. `std::vector::push_back()` occurs, allocating memory on the heap;
6. `main` exits;
7. The `lib_debug` heap analyser singleton goes out of scope, which sees that the `vector` hasn't freed its memory - reports error;
8. The `vector` goes out of global scope, releasing its memory;
9. Program terminates.

Therefore, is there any way we can guarantee that our `LD_PRELOADed` singleton is always the last thing to be deleted, and therefore catch every single `free` that occurs in our application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you are using `GCC` as your compiler. You can define a function in your library to act as a `constructor`, so that code gets executed when your library is loaded.

```
static int initialize_lib_debug () __attribute__((constructor));

static int initialize_lib_debug () {
    /* ... */
}
```